# According to the Hanafi school, can I pray in a shirt that has a print about worshiping other gods?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, hanafi, clothing

I have a shirt which I got from a metal concert from a band that I enjoy.  On the back of the shirt, some of the song lyrics are printed which say "We are worshipping the gods that keep twisting our thoughts."

The song does not promote shirk at all, and actually it is condemning the materialism of the world, but because the lyrics say worshipping and gods it can be confusing.

**Question:** Is it okay if I pray in this shirt generally speaking?  What if I wear it into a masjid because I am already wearing the shirt and want to pray in congregation nearby when the time to pray comes and I don't have time to go home and change?

I only want an answer that uses Hanafi references and not opinions.

Comment: Being Hanafi I won't like to wear such slogan/text and I won't advocate it is not "shirk" I suggest you should no go near shirk even if it is not shirk.

Comment: Regardless of the intent, that statement is a statement of Shirk. I personally wouldn't even buy such a shirt, much less wear it. There's no reason to put your faith at risk. And anyways, don't you have other shirts? This is not a matter of any Madhab - this is a matter of Creed/Aqeedah, and there is no difference in that between the Madahib. Allah knows best

Answer (score -1):

Your commenter above, who says he is Hanafi, gave you good advice. I just have a suggestion but am too new to comment about it: have you considered turning the shirt inside out? Alternatively on Fridays, wear another shirt. When you pray, it shouldn't affect your salat—the Quran, a source accepted by all schools of Islamic thought—only enjoins modesty in dress. For this type of question, one of the most frequent phrases in the Quran should guide you here:
"Will you not use your minds?" 
"Afa laa t'aqiloon?"